# Clip raster where another raster is 1 in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, clip, netcdf

I have two raster layers. One .tiff file with precipitation. And one .tiff layer which is representing my study area. The latter layer is made with value 0 = NOT-study-area, and 1 = study-area. This is the first picture below.

The second layer is the precipitation, which is the second image below. As can be seen, the precipitation layer is covering a bigger extent than my study area. How can I 'clip' the precipitation raster layer where the values of the study area are 1. I put clip in between apostrophes because I am not sure if this is the right tool or handling.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Con('small', 'big')

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the raster calculator:

```
SetNull(Con("Reclass_stat1",0),"tiffexporttest.tif_January")
```